# How to solve [Error 414 Response] when inputing long query string into GET function?

Tags: python, rest, post, get

I'm working with a `Restful API` and I'm feeding a long list (>2000 characters) into the `GET` function and it's returning a `Error 404 Response`. I understand that the URI is too long and was wondering what the best way of retrieving all data in the list instead of repeating the `GET` function multiple times for chunks of the string. I am aware of the `POST` function however was unsure how to apply it.

API documentation can be found here https://docs.skinport.com/

```
# The string input is comma delimited i.e '1st Lieutenant Farlow | SWAT,2020 RMR Challengers'

def api_request():
    
    data_packet = \
        requests.get('https://api.skinport.com/v1/sales/history',
                     params={'app_id': 730, 'currency': 'AUD',
                     'market_hash_name': ('{item_list}').format(item_list = string_format)
                     }).json
        
    return(data_packet)
```

Comment: You are already using the post method by saying `requests.post`

Comment: Hey, I overlooked the code snippet I posted which used `post` instead of `get`. Please see the amended version now.

Comment: from the [docs](https://docs.skinport.com/?python#interacting-with-the-api) It says that status code 404 means that the search came back empty. Does sending just one item in the list work?

Comment: Yeah it does, however when I use a string with >2000 characters it gives me error 414. If you use `post` with the same code you'll return 404.

Comment: It says that post will try to create a new resource. So multiple requests will be required unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

According to your API docs, you want to use a `GET` request, not `POST`.

So just switching `requests.post` to `requests.get` should solve your problem :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I made a silly mistake whilst posting - the current code uses `get` instead of `post` and was an oversight on my behalf.